# Is there a way I can pass a grid name or a parameter into a tapped event?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have this code and somehow I want to get the text value of the first label to the tapped event in the CS code. As the tapped event is on the grid I had an idea of putting the text value into x:Name.

```
<ViewCell >
   <Grid VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"  x:Name="{Binding [0].Name}" Tapped="atiSelectValueX" >
      <local:StyledLabel Text="{Binding [0].Name}" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" />
      <local:StyledLabel IsVisible="{Binding [0].IsSelected}" TextColor="Gray" HorizontalOptions="End" Text="x" />
   </Grid>
</ViewCell>
```

The CS code I have so far:

```
    void atiSelectValueX(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var cell = sender as Grid;
        if (cell == null)
            return;

        var selected = cell. <<< I want to get the name here
```

What I would like to do is to get the x:Name value in the CS code.  I was hoping to get the sender information but it seems like I cannot enter

```
cell.Name
```

Is there another way I can get a parameter like the name (which is the same as the text in the first label always) in the C# code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The x:Name is metadata used by the XAML tools, not an actual property of the object.  You could also bind Name to an unused property, like StyleID, and access that instead

```
<Grid VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" StyleId="{Binding [0].Name}" ...
```

and then

```
var selected = cell.StyleId;
```

Comment: Thanks Jason. That sound like a good idea.  Is there also a way I could do it with a parameter?  I saw something about parameters but could not find a good example that had both the XAML and the CS.

Comment: I'm accepting as your answer is good but will post another question for an idea I have.  thanks